# Errors when I try to migrate in Django2

Tags: python, django

I have a problem (at least I think). I am new in all this, so I apologize If I ask something stupid. 
I have some site, which is working normally. When I try to make migrations ( `python manage.py makemigrations`), everything passed ok, I got the message of how many models new I have, etc. But, when I run after that migrate, I got the following output:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, comments, contenttypes, news, sessions
  Running migrations:
   Applying comments.0003_auto_20180816_2158...Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WITH ORDINALITY"
  LINE 6:                     FROM unnest(c.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY co...
                                              ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
 File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File 
  ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
   output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File 
".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
   File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 203, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
   File 


 ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 531, in _alter_field
fk_names = self._constraint_names(model, [old_field.column], 
foreign_key=True)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 1027, in _constraint_names
constraints = self.connection.introspection.get_constraints(cursor, model._meta.db_table)
 File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/introspection.py", line 158, in get_constraints
""", ["public", table_name])
 File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", 
 line 100, in execute
   return super().execute(sql, params)
 File 


".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
   return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WITH 
ORDINALITY"
LINE 6:                     FROM unnest(c.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY co...
                                              ^
```

Anyway, if after that I try again to make migrations,  got the message that I don't have migrations. So, Django did the job, But this error is here constantly when I try to migrate, I am really wondering why. I tried to google it, but I got nothing.

Comment: remove migrations folder in each app.

Comment: @LeLouch You are kidding me, right? I know to read. :D That is in utils.py file, which does not file that I created or changed. Something that I have done, probably cause that error in Django automatic created file - utils.py

Comment: @MohammadAli Thank you again !!! I couldn't be grateful more! Please, write that as a response and I will accept it. :)

Comment: If you are using Postgres, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51927443/1556106)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must remove migration folders in each app

then, you can use migration commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: This would won't work on many corner cases. Kindly avoid deleting migration folder for any migration issue. I used to do the same mistake until I got trapped on this. I'm writing a detailed answer on how to do migration and solve migration issues, which I has helped me till date.

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you are adding any new field and ***facing migrate error***.

Kindly follow these steps:

- Delete all migration files(not the migration folder, keep the `__init__.py` file
- Truncate the `django_migrations` table
- comment out the new field which is to be added from the *models.py*.  *(Do make sure this step otherwise Django will throw an error when you would follow the below steps)*
- run `python manage.py makemigrations`
- run `python manage.py migrate --fake`
- Uncomment the new field to be added
- run `python manage.py makemigrations`
- run `python manage.py migrate`

Generally, these steps solve any kind of migration problem.

**P.S.** : When you face a problem in only one app, I would recommend to delete entries of that particular app from the **django_migrations** table

If you are looking for solutions which can be applied to production, you can refer to this blog [How to fix Django migrations error](https://thetldr.tech/how-to-fix-any-django-migration-issue-in-local/)

Comment: Thank you @agro ! 
I thumbed up your response and confirmed Mohammad because his comment helped me a day ago.  But your response is more detailed and I hope it will have so much more thumbs up!

Comment: You can follow the same steps in production also, just make sure noone else is deploying to prod during that time. The steps mentioned above is a pseudo squash migration procedure. You can always `squash migration` and then do the migration

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with `postgresql-server-9.2.24-1.el7_5.x86_64` that is installing in `Centos 7` by default. Installing `Postgresql 11` solved the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, but none of the solutions above work. I guess I have to upgrade...

Comment: It seems it only exists since `PostgreSQL 9.4`