# Error in migrating Kiwi with postgrsql in centos

Tags: django, python-3.x, centos, django-migrations, kiwi-tcms

When i load Kiwi database schema in centos6 with python3.6 in postgresql a programming error comes up with following `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WITH ORDINALITY"
LINE 6:`

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, attachments, auth, contenttypes, core, django_comments, kiwi_auth, linkreference, management, sessions, sites, testcases, testplans, testruns
Running migrations:
  Applying testruns.0004_squashed...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "WITH ORDINALITY"
LINE 6:                     FROM unnest(c.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY co...
                                                  ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 535, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 124, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 543, in _alter_field
    fk_names = self._constraint_names(model, [old_field.column], foreign_key=True)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 1115, in _constraint_names
    constraints = self.connection.introspection.get_constraints(cursor, model._meta.db_table)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/introspection.py", line 175, in get_constraints
    """, ["public", table_name])
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WITH ORDINALITY"
LINE 6:                     FROM unnest(c.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY co...
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903606/errors-when-i-try-to-migrate-in-django2

Answer (score 1):

I found what was the issue in my case. I had installed PostgreSQL server version(9.2) which is incompatible with django2.4. After i replaced it with PostgreSQL 10 it worked fine.