# error with migration when i deploy my project

Tags: python, django, migrate

hi my friends this is my site http://qhse-erp.com/
i got this error
[image]
also
i have troble when migrate my module by django on cpanel

i use phpPgAdmin PostgreSQL 9.2.24(i can't use more update from that because this is the share-host , i can't use the root).

django 2.2.6

i got following error when migrare but when i use migrate fake , the error disapear but the site can't be lunch

this is following error

```
Running migrations:
  Applying authtoken.0002_auto_20160226_1747...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aeraeg/virtualenv/python/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "WITH ORDINALITY"
LINE 6:                     FROM unnest(c.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY co...
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903606/errors-when-i-try-to-migrate-in-django2

Comment: thanks Harsh Biyni for that , but i apply this solution befor but my site can't be lunch

Answer (score 0):

sir, You can try this one

1. First delete previous migrations file.
2. Then migrate it again by following statements and

   `python manage.py makemigrations`
   `python manage.py migrate`

Please tell me if it works for you.

Comment: ok Vishal Pndey , we update the version  phpgadmine ,ts is PostgreSQL 9.2.24 now, but the same error (i can't use more update from that because this is the share-host , i can't use the root). i ubdate my question , so please update your answer